# How to set session attribute without login?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a web application and I will redirect user to another website and user will return from this site back to the my application.

I want to set some unique id to this user's session to check some parameters. Problem is the user is **not logged in**. How can I add a session attribute to this user?

```
public ModelAndView redirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Long uniqueId = generateUniqueId();
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("redirect:" + redirectUrl);
    //I need to add uniqueId to user's session
    return mv;
}

public ModelAndView redirectBack(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String uniqueId= ServletRequestUtils.getStringParameter(request, "uniqueId", null);
    String uniqueIdFromSession= (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("uniqueId");
    if(uniqueId.equals(uniqueIdFromSession))
       ....
}
```

Comment: The same way you would add it if the user was logged in. Whether the user is logged in or not doesn't change anything.